# Google Forms, Drive and Slides integration

Tags: google-drive-api, google-forms, google-slides-api

I want to build a Google Form that allows a user to:

1. Select from a menu / index of items which correspond to Google Slides (stored in Google Drive), and
2. Upon the user clicking 'Submit', will trigger the user's selected slides to be concatenated / appended back to back into one custom Google Slide document based on the user's selections, PDFed, and emailed to the user.

The menu / index in the Google Form can be static, as can the underlying mapping table which would map the user's selections to the underlying Slides objects in Google Drive.

I have development experience, but not in Google App Script. If someone can point me in the right direction, or even tell me if this is feasible or not, that would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
Wayne

Comment: Hi, please [check this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask. Your question should be more specific rather than asking for guidance on how to build that. For that case the best is to go to [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/).